# Function returning None instead of expected output

Tags: python-3.x

This code is supposed to find the number which is biggest and then it should print out how many is there, but for some reason this commented if statement doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys

def birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar):
    j=1
    b=0
    f=0
    maxn=0
    for f in range(0,n-1,1):
        b=ar[f]
      #  if maxn==b:
            j=j+1
        elif b>maxn:
            maxn=b
        print(j)    



n = 4 
ar = 3, 1, 2, 3
print(birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar))
```

and when i run this code the output is:

```
1
1
1
None
```

so, final answer is supposed to be 2 instead of None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `None` output is coming from your attempt to print a function which doesn't return anything. Your last line should only be:

```
birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar)
```

You're also off by one in your range statement. The `stop` parameter is up to but not including. Your array positions are 0-3 so your stop parameter should be 4. E.g.:

```
for f in range(0,n,1):
```

Although, the `start` and `step` are default anyway so for readability, you can just have `range(n):`

Answer (score 0):

In your code

first of all, you are not `return`ing anything from your function,

second thing, you are iterating over `n-1` elements of your collection of numbers, you can fix this: by using `range(0, n, 1)`,

third, in the `elif` part you are not resetting `j`'s value to 1 again.

With all three fixes:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys

def birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar):
    j=1
    b=0
    f=0
    maxn=ar[0]
    for f in range(1,n,1):
        b=ar[f]
        if maxn==b:
            j=j+1
        elif b>maxn:
            maxn=b
            j = 1
        print(j)    
return j


n = 4 
ar = 3, 1, 2, 3
print(birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar))
```

Another solution that can help:

```
def birthdayCakeCandles(ar):

    maxNum = max(ar)
    maxNumTimes = ar.count(maxNum)

    return maxNum, maxNumTimes


print(birthdayCakeCandles([3, 3, 2, 1, 1,1]))
# output: (3, 2)
```

Comment: heres a simpler one return ar.count(max(ar)), but thats not what i want, i want to understand why my written code doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you ask a question in StackOverflow, it's a good idea to use meaningful variable names such as "counter", "num", "array", "name_input", etc. This will help other people quickly understand why you are using that variable. If your code is difficult to understand, most people will just ignore your question. Please re-write your question and edit your code sample so that it has variable names that are more understandable and meaningful.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @Roope I don't have enough reputation points to comment on a question therefore, I had to answer like this. Once the writer of the question has properly explained his question, I will edit my answer to help him with his problem.